# Taking a picture via the webcam when someone logs in or tries to log in (on Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, webcam

I was wondering, as a security measure, wouldn't it be nice if the webcam were used to take a picture whenever someone would try to log into the computer (especially given that nowadays almost every device has one on the front of the screen). Then each picture could be stored into a folder which could only be accessed with administrator privileges. The advantage of this would be that, given that a user thinking someone else has logged into their computer may only realize this at a later time and may not be checking for unauthorized accesses or accesses via stolen password on a daily basis, *the list of dates and times will not make sense*, that is, the user won't know whether a certain access was made by them because they won't remember if they logged in on a distant date, perhaps not even the time for some login which might have even happened on the same date.

So, is there a way to enable (perhaps even via some third-party software), so that upon logging in a picture is automatically taken and stored with the date and time as part of the filename in a special folder? A user will expect their fact to be present on each of these pictures. If a face on one of the pictures is someone else's (or even if the face is missing) it will be easily spotted on a gallery application for viewing all the pictures together, and any possible unauthorized access or login attempt will be easily detected on such a computer.

How can I install or configure this feature on Windows 7?

Comment: This could be done through a custom application easily enough.  There isn't a feature built-in Windows thought that does this.

Comment: You would need to script it but many webcam applications have some commandline functionality. You could then write a logon/logoff script triggered by a scheduled task or by Group Policy. The script would need to run with Administrator privileges if you want it to write to a folder that only an administrator can access. Potentially a good idea but if the laptop is stolen, for example, then a good thief would immediately "factory restore" the device and keep it off the Internet so your program is useless...

Comment: Of course if you are that worried about unauthorized access to a machine just don't provide the authentication information to random people or have restricted profile designated for that purpose.

Comment: The scenario I have in mind is one where some close friend sharing the same living space comes to know your password (by pure chance of course, perhaps by sneaking up behind you while you're using the computer or by some other technique) and then decides to secretly sneak into your account to browse your stuff. This is not the case where a laptop would be gone stolen, but the app I am asking for would be extremely useful in this scenario (provided of course that the admin password is not leaked as well, and even if so, the app and its webcam pics would reside in some hidden place).

Comment: @BigChris, the [YawCam application](http://www.yawcam.com/index.php) is a free webcam application which seems to be pretty good and is also feature rich. Given that it can run as a "Windows Service", I wonder whether you could kindly provide a script to achieve the desired effect, perhaps with instructions on how to install it as a service. Thanks a lot.